# Easypubmed xml output not in xml

Tags: r, xml, pubmed

I am trying to get the output of the following code into a dataframe:

```
library(easyPubMed)

pmid_list=['35566889','33538053', '30848212']

pmxml <- fetch_pubmed_data_by_PMID(pmid_list,format='asn.1')

require(XML)

xml_data <- xmlToList(pmxml)
```

According to the documentation the output is in xml. However I get the error:

Error: XML content does not seem to be XML .. Any ideas on how I can convert the output to a dataframe? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer to this. Anyway, there are a few things I noticed:

1. the `pmid_list` vector needs to be defined using the `c()` function (unlike python)
2. the 'asn.1' format is not supposed to return XML, so that is sort of an issue.
3. `easyPubMed` includes a function (see code below) to cast XML output into `data.frame`

Assuming you are working with `easyPubMed` version 2.22 (available on GitHub at `dami82/easyPubMed`), you may want to have a look at the following code.

```
library(easyPubMed)
pmid_list <- c('35566889','33538053', '30848212')
pmxml <- fetch_pubmed_data_by_PMID(pmid_list, format = 'xml', encoding = 'UTF-8')
pmdf <- table_articles_byAuth(pubmed_data = pmxml, included_authors = 'first', getKeywords = TRUE)

pmdf[, 1:2]
#pmid                               doi
#1 35566889             10.3390/polym14091720
#2 33538053            10.1002/cbdv.202000906
#3 30848212 10.2174/1871520619666190307115231
```

If you prefer to parse XML using the `XML` library, you can do so as follows.

```
xd <- XML::xmlParse(pmxml, asText = TRUE)
els <- XML::getNodeSet(xd, path = '//ArticleTitle')
els[[1]]
#<ArticleTitle>The Use of Branching Agents in the Synthesis of PBAT.</ArticleTitle>
```

Please note that additional help to cast PubMed records into `data.frame` objects can be found in the package vignette (*e.g.,* `vignette("getting_started_with_easyPubMed")` ) as well as in the manual of the `table_articles_byAuth()` function (*e.g.,* see `?easyPubMed::table_articles_byAuth`).